# maclaurin series for sin(x)

Tags: vb.net, trigonometry

I wrote a program to calculate sin(x) using the Maclaurin series but when I tried debugging it, it is giving an overflow error. Here is the code, can anyone help me out?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Function sin(ByVal x As Double) As Double
        Dim sinx, radx, abc As Double
        sinx = 0
        radx = x * Math.PI / 180
        For i = 1 To 20 Step 2
            abc = (Math.Pow(-1, (i / 2)) * Math.Pow(radx, i)) / factorial(i)
            sinx += abc
        Next
        Return sinx
    End Function

    Private Function factorial(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
        If (n = 0) Or (n = 1) Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return n * factorial(n - 1)
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalc.Click
        Dim x As Integer
        x = Val(TxtInput.Text)
        TxtAns.Text = sin(x)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: One problem is that your loop is trying to calculate the factorial of 20 which is too big to fit in an Integer. It should fit in a Long though, So try changing the Factorial function to return a Long.

Comment: @blackwood  I  just tried long and debugged it ,I got an output of "Nan"

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the Maclaurin series, so I can be of limited help. One reason for the NaN (Not a Number) is that your loop is trying to raise -1 to the power of x.5 (in other words calculate the square root of -1). Are you sure you are implementing the correct algorithm?

Comment: yes I am  sure of that

Comment: So the series is calculated using complex numbers (square root of -1)?

Comment: Is it possible that the loop is supposed to be `For i = 2 To 20 Step 2` (all the even numbers from 2 to 20)?

Comment: You must use integer division to prevent the Math.Pow() function from failing.  Use `Math.Pow(-1, (i \ 2))`, note the backslash instead of /

Answer (score 0):

the below code gives the answer for the sine of an angle using Maclaurin series

for your interface you need 2 labels, 2 textboxes and 3 buttons

Public Class Maclaurin_series

```
Private Function sin(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Dim sinx, radx, abc As Double
    sinx = 0
    radx = x * Math.PI / 180
    For i = 1 To 20 Step 2
        abc = (Math.Pow(-1, (i \ 2)) * Math.Pow(radx, i)) / factorial(i)
        sinx += abc
    Next
    Return sinx
End Function

Private Function factorial(ByVal n As Integer) As Long

    If (n = 0) Or (n = 1) Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return n * factorial(n - 1)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub BtnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalc.Click
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Val(TxtInput.Text)
    TxtAns.Text = sin(x)
End Sub


Private Sub BtnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TxtAns.Text = ""

    TxtInput.Text = " "
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Sub testDBLCOS()
Debug.Print "VBA COS", Cos(0.25 * Pi)
Debug.Print "TAYLOR", DBLCOS(0.25 * Pi), "DELTA", DBLCOS(0.25 * Pi) - Cos(0.25 * Pi)
End Sub

Sub testDBLSIN()
Debug.Print "VBA SIN", sin(0.25 * Pi)
Debug.Print "TAYLOR", DBLSIN(0.25 * Pi), "DELTA", DBLSIN(0.25 * Pi) - sin(0.25 * Pi)
End Sub

Function DBLCOS(x, Optional ITER As Long = 10) As Double
    Dim P, k, x2, d, f, c As Double
    f = 2
    c = 2
    k = 1
    x2 = x * x
    SUM = 1
    P = 1
    For I = 1 To ITER
        k = -k
        P = P * x2
        SUM = SUM + k * P / f
        c = c + 1
        f = f * c
        c = c + 1
        f = f * c
    Next
    DBLCOS = SUM
End Function
 Function DBLSIN(x, Optional ITER As Long = 10) As Double
    Dim P, k, x2, d, f, c As Double
    k = 1
    c = 3
    f = 6
    P = x
    x2 = x * x
    SUM = x
    For I = 1 To ITER
        k = -k
        P = P * x2
        SUM = SUM + k * P / f
        c = c + 1
        f = f * c
        c = c + 1
        f = f * c
    Next
    DBLSIN = SUM
End Function